# Which rows were deleted?

Tags: sqlite

SQL newbie here. Say I wanted to delete certain entries from a table, but also know which entries got deleted. Is there a better way or should I just do a `SELECT` before `DELETE`? Specifically, I'm using SQLite.

```
-- Stupid minimal table example so no types included
CREATE TABLE a_table (value1, value2);

-- Inserting some rows
INSERT INTO a_table (value1, value2) VALUES
        ('hi', 'all'),
        ('hello', 'world'),
        ('not', 'deleting');

-- Tedious, repetitive. Any better way?
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT value1, value2
    FROM a_table
    WHERE value1 <> 'not';
DELETE FROM a_table
    WHERE value1 <> 'not';
COMMIT;
```

This doesn't look too bad, but can quickly get ugly as `WHERE` becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: You can't do a select and delete at the same time, and a delete does not return any records.  Just wrap your current select and delete in a transaction and off you go.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fixing to include a transaction. But still, it can get ugly quickly when the where condition gets big.

Comment: The ugliness (or beauty) of the query isn't as much a concern as the performance and the size of the result set which gets returned.  But upvoted on spec that there is a silver bullet answer I can't see here.

Comment: @relatively_random If you just want to log what you're deleting, you could look into adding a [trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Comment: @glibud Unfortunately, triggers won't help as far as I'm aware. Specifically, I want to delete files outside the DB, that are referenced by the rows I'm deleting.